# Expanded div runs through footer

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I have a page with a tableview. When you click the show more button, more details appear under each line. The outer div (with the double lines) sizes correctly when the content changes when I don't have my footer added to the page.

When I add my footer the resizing of the outer div breaks somehow and the contents of the expanded table run through my footer. I have been playing with absolute/relative footer locations and different display types of the footer, but I can't get it to work.

How can I solve this?

```css
/* Generic */
html, body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background-color: #404040;
    color: #ffffff;
}
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 5.5vh;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
}

.container--padding {
    padding-top: 10vh;
}

.shorten {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
h2 {
    padding-top: 12vh;
    font-family: Lora, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.9vh;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 100%;
}
.link a {
    text-indent: 3em;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.link a:hover {
    text-indent: 3em;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #404040;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    padding: 5px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

/* Block: Header */

.container-padding-home {
    padding-top: 30vh;
}
.homepage-header h1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 5.5vh;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
}

.homepage-header h2 {
    padding-top: 15vh;
    font-family: Lora, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.9vh;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 100%;
}
.homepage-block {
    height:100vh;
    }
.header-block {
    height: 50vh;
}

/* Block: Tile Menu */
.tile-menu {
    padding: 20px 15px 20px 15px;
}
.thumbnail {
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.thumbnail:after {
    content: "\A";
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:110%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:
            linear-gradient(
                    rgba(255,255,255,0.2),
                    rgba(255,255,255,0.2)
            ),
            url(../../images/focus.png) no-repeat center;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.thumbnail:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
.caption {
    width:100%;
    bottom: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #404040;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #404040 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #404040 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #404040 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #404040 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.caption h3 {
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* Block: Contact */
.contact-form h3 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.subtitle {
    display: block;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #cccccc;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: Lora, serif;
}
.contact {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #404040;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.43;
    min-height: 3.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 1.07em 0.5em;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    display: block;
}
.btn-rwdb {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-color: #404040;
    color: #404040;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.btn-rwdb:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #404040;
    border-color: #404040;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

/* Block: Overview */
#overview {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.overview {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.overview img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.card-title {
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.card-subtitle {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
    color: #cccccc;
    margin-top: -1rem;
    line-height: 1.7857;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn-card {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-color: #404040;
    color: #404040;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.btn-card:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #404040;
    border-color: #404040;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

/* Block: Search */
#imaginary_container {
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 7%;
}
.stylish-input-group .input-group-addon {
    background: #cccccc !important;
}
.stylish-input-group .form-control {
    border-right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0;
    border-color: #cccccc;
}
.stylish-input-group button {
    border:0;
    background:transparent;
}

/* Block: Lyric */
.lyric-detail {
    padding-bottom: 10vh;
}

/* Block: Table */
.table-header {
    border: 2px #515151;
    border-top-style: solid;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.table-body {
    border: 1px #515151;
    border-top-style: solid;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.cancelled {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #808080;
}

/* Block: Google Maps */
#map_wrapper {
    height: 600px;
    color: #404040;
}
#map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*Block: Discography Details*/
.disc-details {
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.disc-padding {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.disc-border {
    border: 3px double #515151;
}
.disc-specs {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.details {
    display: none;
}
.btn-details {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-color: #404040;
    color: #404040;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 38%;
}
.btn-details:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #404040;
    border-color: #404040;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
/*Block: Footer */
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.copyright {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.layout-margin-top {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic&amp;subset=latin">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.rwdb.info/assets/tether/tether.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.rwdb.info/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.rwdb.info/assets/animate/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.rwdb.info/assets/rwdb-custom/rwdb-custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.rwdb.info/assets/rwdb-custom/rwdb-menu.css">


</head>
<body>
<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="/" class="navbar-logo"><img src="/images/rwdb-logo.png" alt="RWDB"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MAIN #1
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub #1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub #1-2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MAIN #2
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub #2-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub #2-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub #2-3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub #2-4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub #2-5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub #2-6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">MAIN #3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">MAIN #4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<section class="header-block" style = "background: url('https://paulpichugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/macpac-19-960x636.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
    <div class="container--padding animated slideInUp">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <h1>Main header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h2>Subheader</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="disc-padding">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="picture-left-text-right-1" class="container disc-border wow fadeInLeft">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 disc-details row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                <img alt="Heavy Entertainment Show" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dB3Dvgf3VIglusoGJAfpNUAANhTXW8K9mvIsiIPkhJUAbAKGKJcEMPTf0mkSexzLM5o=w300" style="width: 100%">
                <div class="row disc-specs">Label: Sony Music<br />Barcode: 8898 5 37103 2<br />Release type: Album<br />Region: Europe</div>
            </div>
            <a id="expandAll" href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Expand All</a>
            <a id="collapseAll" href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Collapse All</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 disc-details row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="headerNumber-1-1" class="col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-1 table-header">#</div>
                    <div id="headerTitle-1-1" class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 table-header">Title</div>
                    <div id="headerLength-1-1" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 table-header">Length</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="accordion" class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-1 table-body">1</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 table-body">Song #1</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 table-body">03:21</div>
                    </a>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Vocals : A </small></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Written by : A B C </small></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body" style="text-align:justify"><small>A B C D </small></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="accordion" class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" class="">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-1 table-body">2</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 table-body">Song #2</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 table-body">03:02</div>
                    </a>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Vocals : A </small></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Written by : A B C </small></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body" style="text-align:justify"><small>A B C D </small></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="accordion" class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" class="">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-1 table-body">3</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 table-body">Song #3</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 table-body">03:45</div>
                    </a>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Vocals : A </small></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Written by : A B C </small></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body" style= "text-align:justify"><small>A B C D </small></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div id="accordion" class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" class="">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-1 table-body">4</div>
                            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 table-body">Song #4</div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 table-body">04:12</div>
                        </a>
                        <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Vocals : A </small></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Written by : A B C </small></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body" style="text-align:justify"><small>A B C D </small></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div id="accordion" class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" class="">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-1 table-body">5</div>
                            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 table-body">Song #5</div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 table-body">03:45</div>
                        </a>
                        <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Vocals : A </small></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Written by : A B C </small></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body" style="text-align:justify"><small>A B C D </small></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="accordion" class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix" class="">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-1 table-body">6</div>
                            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 table-body">Song #6</div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 table-body">03:45</div>
                        </a>
                        <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Vocals : A </small></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body"><small>Written by : A B C </small></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-9 table-body" style="text-align:justify"><small>A B C D </small></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </div>
<!--scripts loaded here-->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script>
    $(function () {
        $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click',function() {
            var objectID=$(this).attr('href');
            if($(objectID).hasClass('in')) {
                $(objectID).collapse('hide');
            }
            else {
                $(objectID).collapse('show');
            }
        });
        $('#expandAll').on('click',function(){
            $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function(){
                var objectID=$(this).attr('href');
                if($(objectID).hasClass('in')===false)
                {
                    $(objectID).collapse('show');
                }
            });
        });
        $('#collapseAll').on('click',function(){
            $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function(){
                var objectID=$(this).attr('href');
                $(objectID).collapse('hide');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</div>

<!-- When I add this it breaks -->
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row layout-margin-top">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
               <ul>
                   <li class="link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <ul>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">Privacy &amp; Cookies Policy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <ul>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row copyrightcol-xs-12">&copy; Copyright 2017. All rights reserved.</div>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.rwdb.info/assets/matchheight/jquery.matchHeight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.rwdb.info/assets/rwdb-custom/rwdb-custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.rwdb.info/assets/tether/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.rwdb.info/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "row-eq-height" from the line:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 disc-details row-eq-height">
```

It should expand the container now.

Also check your a[data-toggle="collapse"] function, cause it seems to not collapse the content when clicking a song twice.

Comment: I totally overlooked the row-eq-height. Thanks so much, that did the trick! I also solved the collapse function.